# QML XML list view not working

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qml

I'm new to QML. I cannot get these code working.

**Model.qml**

```
import QtQuick 1.1

XmlListModel {
    source: "./test.xml"
    query: "/tag1/tag2"
    onSourceChanged: {
    console.log("source changed:" + source)
        reload()
    }

    XmlRole { name: "id"; query: "id/string()" }
    XmlRole { name: "name"; query: "name/string()" }
}
```

---

**View.qml**

```
import QtQuick 1.1

ListView {
    width: 200
}
```

---

**TheDelegate.qml**

```
import QtQuick 1.1

Rectangle {
    width: parent.width
    height: 20

    Text {
        text: id + ": " + name
    }
}
```

---

**Main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 1.1

Item {
    id: container

    Model {
        id: resultModel
    objectName: "resultModel"
    }

    View {
        id: resultView
        model: resultModel
        delegate: TheDelegate {}
    }
}
```

---

And in my **main.cpp**:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QDeclarativeView view;
    view.setResizeMode(QDeclarativeView::SizeRootObjectToView);
    view.setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile("./TheMain.qml"));
    view.show();

    int rtnVal = app.exec();
    return rtnVal;
}
```

---

When i run the project, it just shows nothing, no window displayed.

Thanks in advance.

---

**EDIT:**

I use the qmlviewer(4.8.4) to debug my qmls, and i get the warning:

> TheDelegate.qml:18: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: name

But I have to `name` defined in the `XmlRole`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set Height as well for listview.

```
ListView {
    width: 200
    height: parent.height;
}
```